# How can you DisplayAlert from a .NET Maui ContentView?

Tags: maui, contentview, displayalert

I am trying to do something similar to:

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
```

The issue is the button that is triggering this is on a ContentView, not a ContentPage. I understand why it is not available on the view (sort of), but there must be a way to trigger an alert dialogue if your UI object is part of a view I would think.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
App.Current.Mainpage.DisplayAlert(…);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people wondering how to do something similar in .NET Maui Blazor, this is how I got an alert in .NET Maui Blazor.

It is similar to the answer, but we use Application.Current inside namespace Microsoft.Maui.Controls here.

Example usage, note the usage of async/await :

```
   private async Task OnInputFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var imageSaveModel = await ImageSaveService.SaveImage(args.File);
        Model = new IndexModel(imageSaveModel);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"MAUI Blazor ImageAnalyzer app App", $"Wrote file to location : {Model.SavedFilePath} Size is: {Model.FileSize} kB", "Ok", "Cancel");
    }
```

[image: .NET MAUI Blazor alert showing up]